# WAMP localhost server folder not accessing by using browser

Tags: php, localhost, wampserver

I have installed WAMP on my PC. Successfully Installed. I can access phpmyadmin, localhost. When I'm trying to access my local project folder using localhost it's showing a blank page. Here's my local project path URL.

C:\wamp64\www\phpproject. [image: Check my localhost]

I clicked on phpproject on localhost. Please check the below image. *Observe the URL*
[image: Observe the URL]

When I type manually by using "localhost/phpproject/" it's working fine and showing files list.[image] I want to know the reason why this occurs. I googled a lot but didn't find the exact reason. Somewhere I read about changing the value in index.php in the www folder.

*($suppress_localhost ? 'http://' : '')
change http:// to http://localhost/ *

But now the latest version is having a different value in it. Please explain the reason and solution.

Comment: Click on the "Add a Virtual Host" link on the homepage. Follow the instructions to make your `www/phpproject` folder into a Virtual Host DocumentRoot folder.

Comment: I added the Virtual host with the name of "phpfinalmodule" it's working but I want to know why we need to create virtual host for this. Can't we access directly by "localhost" homepage?

Comment: You can, but its not a good idea. Once you move this site to a real hosting package your site will be running in a Virtual Host, so if you code it in an environment that matches its final destination you will get less (maybe no) problems when you come to do that

Comment: You should try Devserver instead (www.easyphp.org). Wampserver is outdated.